# write bash file to do incremntal backup daily?

Tags: linux, backup, svn, repository, incremental-backup

i want to write bash file to do incremntal backup daily ... how i can do it ?

by `svnlook youngest` i can get the current svn repository revision ... how i can store the result of `svnlook youngest` in variable and how i can take the differant between to revision

to understand what i mean see the following :-
`svnadmin dump $SVN_REPOSITORY --revision old_revision_number:YOUNGEST_revision_number  --incremental > $SHERD_AREA/incremental_backup"`

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/194858/143631 has the full scripts needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
version=$(svnlook youngest)
```