# Getting error "svnadmin: File already exists" for `svnadmin load`

Tags: svn

I am struggling trying to load a incremental SVN backup made using `svnadmin dump  --incremental`.

I have based my backup script on the ServerFault post:
[Incremental Backups of SVN Repository daily ? (OS = UNIX)](https://serverfault.com/questions/194845/incremental-backups-of-svn-repository-daily-os-unix)

The first revision of each new backup is the last revision of the previous backup, is this correct?

E.g.:

> - Backup1: rev 0 to rev 100
> - Backup2: rev 100 to 154
> - etc

When I'm trying to load these backups into a new server (using `svnadmin load`), I am getting the error `svnadmin: File already exists` errors for the first revision in the second backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your backup1 and backup2 dumps contain a revision that exists in both of them: rev 100. So when performing `svnadmin dump` with `--incremental` on a range of revisions make sure that these dumps don't overlap.

For example in your case the *backup1* and *backup2* should contain:

> Backup1: rev 0 to 99
>
> Backup2: rev 100 to 154
>
> Backup3: rev 155 to 199

Here is a sample from the [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.migrate.svnadmin):

```
$ svnadmin dump myrepos -r 0:1000 > dumpfile1
$ svnadmin dump myrepos -r 1001:2000 --incremental > dumpfile2
$ svnadmin dump myrepos -r 2001:3000 --incremental > dumpfile3
```

Comment: Hi Bahrep, thank you for the info! I don't have enough reputation to be able to comment on the original proposed solution, perhaps you can so others don't have the issue I had?

Answer (score 2):

While using svnload you can try in this way

svnadmin load D:\Repositories\RepoName < E:\Dump_1-100.dump

svnadmin load -r 101:154 D:\Repositories\RepoName < E:\Dump_100-154.dump